# Spacebar doesnt work in python shell or pdb

Tags: shell, python, readline, debugger

Was hoping someone here may have experienced this too. I often use ipython for a local python shell and everything works fine. But sometime I like to use pdb and the default python shell. I'm using mac terminal but I am unable to space. If anyone has encountered this and knows whats up, or can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer with some help from some coworkers.

In my `$HOME/.inputrc` I had `Space: magic-space` set

So I changed it to:

```
$if Bash
    Space: magic-space
$endif
```

Hope this helps some weary soul in the future.